# Proof verification for $f^{-1}(B_1\cup B_2)=f^{-1}(B_1)\cup f^{-1}(B_2)$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, proof-writing

For my Analysis 1 class, I need to solve this problem:

> Let $f:A\rightarrow B \,$ be a function and let $A_1,A_2\subseteq A$ and $B_1,B_2\subseteq B$.
>
> (a) Prove that $f^{-1}(B_1\cup B_2)=f^{-1}(B_1)\cup f^{-1}(B_2)$

**MY SOLUTION**

$$\begin{align}
\text{Let } x\in f^{-1}(B_1\cup B_2) \, &\iff \, f(x)\in B_1\cup B_2 \\
                &\iff \, f(x)\in B_1 \text{ or } f(x)\in B_2 \\
                &\iff \, x\in f^{-1}(B_1) \text{ or } x\in f^{-1}(B_2) \\
                &\iff \, x\in f^{-1}(B_1)\cup f^{-1}(B_2)
\end{align}$$

I was wondering if my solution was enough or do I have to decompose my solution to prove one side then the other ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Your proof is fine. If you are looking for a pedantic nitpick you could start with "Let $x \in A$" and then begin the equivalencies rather than starting with $x \in f^{-1}(B_i \cup B_2)$.